# Disprove $\{(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))),(\exists y P(y))\}\vdash(\exists x Q(x))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

> Given the statement $$\{(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))),(\exists y P(y))\}\vdash(\exists x Q(x))$$
>
> Show that there is no natural deduction proof for the statement.

I know I need to use the completeness property of natural deduction in the predicate case, but I need some help exhibiting a contradiction. I know that I need to find a interpretation where the $(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x)))$and $(\exists y P(y))$ holds for any predicate P and Q, but $(\exists x Q(x))$ is false. But I'm having trouble coming up with anything.

I can understand showing the entailment $\{(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))),(\exists y P(y))\}\nvDash(\exists x Q(x))$ for one choice of $P$ and $Q$, but to get the correct answer, it seems like I need to show that for any $P$ and $Q$, the entailment doesn't hold.

Comment: Can't you think of an interpretation where $\exists xP(x)$ and $\exists x\neg P(x)$ are both true, while $\exists xQ(x)$ is false?

Comment: @bof to do that, don't I have to specify (on some level) what P and Q is? Which is something weaker than what the question want, which is to show the entailment doesn't hold $\forall P, \forall Q$ (which I honestly don't understand why is needed, but is apparently there).

Comment: Consider a bag with $n$ balls inside: $n-1$ are Black and the last one is Red. Interpret $P$ as "is Black" and interpret $Q$ as "is White". Clearly: $\exists x Px$ is satisfied in this interpretation, while $\exists x Qx$ is not (no White balls). now for $\exists x (Px \to Qx)$; the Red ball is such that both $P$ and $Q$ do not hold of it. Thus, $Px \to Qx$ is True of it.

Comment: Obviously there are choices of $P$ and $Q$ such that you can actually prove $\exists x Q(x)$, so I don't think that you need to prove that for any choice of $P$ and $Q$ that you can't prove $\exists x Q(x)$. Instead it should be interpreted as that there are choices of $P$ and $Q$ such that $\exists x Q(x)$ can't be proven (yet the prerequisites are actually true).

Comment: $\vDash$ means "for all interpretatons ...". $\nvDash$ means "not for all interpretations", which is equivalent to "there exists an interpretation such that not". So with $\nvDash$ you have meta-logically $\exists P \exists Q$, *not* $\forall P \forall Q$. Showing $\{(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))),(\exists y P(y))\}\nvDash(\exists x Q(x))$ means showing at least *one* structure, i.e. *one* interpretation of $P$ and $Q$ for which the entailment doesn't hold. It is *not* necessary for the proof of $\nvDash$ that for *any* interpretation for $P$ and $Q$ the entailment doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Counterexample*: consider a bag with $n$ balls inside, $n−1$ of which are Black and the last one is Red.

Interpret $P$ as "is Black" and interpret $Q$ as "is White".

Clearly: $∃yPy$ is satisfied by this interpretation, while $∃xQx$ is not (no White balls).

What about $∃x(Px→Qx)$ ? Call $r$ the Red ball: it is such that both $P$ an $Q$ do not hold of it. Thus, $Pr → Qr$ is True (False $\to$ False is True) and thus the above interpretation satisfies $∃x(Px→Qx)$.

Having found an interpretation that satisfies the premises and not the conclusion, we can conclude that:

> $∃x(Px→Qx), ∃yPy \nvDash ∃xQx$.

Comment: I wanted to do a more interesting one.  Where $Px$ says "$x$ is an odd number" and $Qx$ says "$x$ is an odd perfect number" ... Both $P6 \to  Q6$ and $P9$ are true ... so then we conclude that there is an odd perfect number!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a countermodel is to use a tree proof generator.  Here is one countermodel:

[image]

This model has a domain with two members. Only for the member $1$ is $P$ true. There is no member that makes $Q$ true.

With that assignment, $\exists x Qx$ is false since $Q$ is false for both members of the domain. This makes the consequent false, but the antecedent is true because for $y=1$ we have $P$ true and for $x=0$ we have $P$ false and $Q$ false making the conditional true.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/trees/